# Batch-file forcing script to remove folder inside subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, del

I need to delete 4 files, and 1 folder in a specific location and in unknown number of subfolders(different names). I would like to keep this as simple as possible. I managed to make this almost work, without any loops, but it doesn't work with folder removal in subfolders. All 4 files are deleted in main folder and all subfolders, but folder "scss" with all his content is still present in subfolders.

How to force this script to additionally delete folder in subfolders too ??

```
START /c cmd %this_dir%
DEL gulp_start.bat, .brackets.json, package.json, gulpfile.js /s /q scss
rmdir scss
```

Comment: Even if `START` was necessary there is no **`/C`** option. Enter `START /?`, `CMD /?`, `DEL /?`and `RMDIR /?` individually at the Command prompt to get the help documentation on each of those commands.

Comment: @Compo Actually "/c" is necessary to autoclose batch-file, and that was not a subject of a question anyway.

Comment: norbidrak, it is generally recommended in any argument or disagreement that your standpoint is at least remotely correct. Had you followed my previous advice and read the help information, you may have been less inclined to have posted that comment! Also, because you mentioned it, you have one command per line; the first does not follow the information in the help pages, it is incorrect! The second does not follow the structure as given in the help pages and the third only follows the information in those pages if it is empty. All of your script is both wrong and the subject of your question.

Comment: @Compo And yet it's working just fine, in contrary removing "/c" makes cmd active after script is finished, so I don't care of available options, it might be Law Of Attraction, God, Satan or anything else, but adding "/c" makes it work. I didn't invent in, I just saw it somewhere else.Your comment though is just a typical annoying "use google"/"read manual" pointless advice, done by "I need to boost my ego" grumpy internet guys, no solution/usefulness, just picking some nerdy irrelevant stuff that no one cares about, only to show that someone is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many ways you try to counter my comments, the fact is that there is no **`/C`** option to `START`, there is however a **`/C`** option to `CMD`, both of which are easily noted by following the advice I provided in my opening comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a For Loop.

#### Example

Add following to your batch.

```
FOR /d /r . %%d IN (scss) DO @IF EXIST "%%d" rd /s /q "%%d"
```